# Reading and writing on I/O ports

Tags: c, embedded, hardware-port

I am trying to understand the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/io.h>

#define baseport 0x378

int main()
{
    int b;
    if(ioperm(baseport,3,1))
    {
        perror("ioperm");
        exit(1);
    }
    outb(0,baseport);

    usleep(1000000);
    printf("\n the status: %x,\n",inb(baseport));

    if (ioperm(baseport,3,0)) {perror("ioperm"); exit(1);}

    exit(0);
}
```

The output is 0xff, 255 in decimal, whether I write on Port 1 or Port 0 (using `outb()`).  I cannot understand why it is 255 when I am writing 0 to it.

Comment: What's supposed to be behind that port, and is it supposed to return anything else than 0xFF?

Comment: @mat its a parallel port i haven't attached anything

Comment: 0x378 is an output port, not an input port.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result of doing inb(0x378) is hardware-dependent. Some chips return the value you have written previously with outb, and some other chips just return garbage. In any case, it is *not* the port to read bytes from a potentially connected device.

Comment: if inb does not read byte on the port then for what it is used....please explain as i am a newbie.......

Comment: @karan - Some ports are just for output, like one connected to a printer. What would you be reading from the printer?

Comment: @BoPersson: its status, but then again, that is at a different, read-only, port, IIRC.

Answer (score -2):

First you need to see the port's capabilities, *input*, *output* or *both*. If it can be configured as *both*, you have to set it to the respective mode and only then you can expect the right behavior.